# How to solve "A nonexistent object was used in an `State` of a Dash callback." when testing dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I have tried to use dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard from github. Everything works OK except daq.NumericInput indicators. They are totally missing from the first tab and when tab is opened error message appears to error log. I have to use more newer versions of some libraries compared to git example. Anyone else tested with never versions with similar error messages?

Link to example: https://dash.gallery/dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard/

Link to github:[https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/commits/main/apps/dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/tree/main/apps/dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard)[3](https://github.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/commits/main/apps/dash-manufacture-spc-dashboard)

Example of definition numericInput:

```
ud_usl_input = daq.NumericInput(
    id="ud_usl_input", className="setting-input", size=200, max=9999999
)
```

Error message:

> A nonexistent object was used in an `State` of a Dash callback. The id
> of this object is `ud_usl_input` and the property is `value`. The
> string ids in the current layout are: [big-app-container, banner,
> banner-text, banner-logo, learn-more-button, logo, interval-component,
> app-container, tabs, app-tabs, Specs-tab, Control-chart-tab,
> app-content, value-setter-store, n-interval-stage, markdown,
> markdown-container, markdown_close, set-specs-intro-container,
> settings-menu, metric-select-menu, metric-select-title,
> metric-select-dropdown, value-setter-menu, value-setter-panel,
> button-div, value-setter-set-btn, value-setter-view-btn,
> value-setter-view-output

]

[image: Pic From Git example]

[image: My version:]

Comment: Please put the link to github as well.

Comment: Good point, now added

Comment: Please add also the error message to your question.

Comment: Added a example of error message. Same error happens with "Output", example is for "State"

Comment: Remove this state to suppress the error.

Answer (score 0):

By using exact versions all works now.

dash==2.6.2 --> 1.0.2
dash-daq== 0.5.0 --> 0.1.7

Hopefully this will be updated someday.